# C# ASP.NET MVC - how to refresh page and load ajax data into my input after POST

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

After POST url, I want to save data and show it in my input text, so different users can see their latest post every time they enter in my website.

HTML in View:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div style="display:inline-block" class="col-md-6">
        <textarea id="Title_1" name="Title_1" style="width:100%" placeholder=""></textarea>
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block" class="col-md-6">
        <textarea id="Content_1" name="Content_1" style="width:100%"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div style="display:inline-block" class="col-md-6">
        <textarea id="Title_2" name="Title_2" style="width:100%""></textarea>
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block" class="col-md-6">
        <textarea id="Content_2" name="Content_2" style="width:100%"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <button onclick="log()" id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">SEND</button>
</div>
```

js in view:

```
function log() {
    var Title_1 = $('#Title_1').val();
    var Title_2 = $('#Title_2').val();
    var Title_3 = $('#Title_3').val();
    var Content_1 = $('#Content_1').val();
    var Content_2 = $('#Content_2').val();
    var Content_3 = $('#Content_3').val();
    var Image=$('input[name=Image]:checked').val()
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://test/jy/GetData.php?' + "Title_1=" + Title_1 + "&Content_1=" + Content_1
            + "&Title_2=" + Title_2 + "&Content_2=" + Content_2 + "&Title_3=" + Title_3 + "&Content_3="
            + Content_3 + "&Image=" + Image,
        type: 'POST',

        success: function (data) { 
        },
        error: function (data) {
        }

    });
}
```

Want to save parameters in url, like Title_1="123",Title_2="456".

Is it possible if i don't store those parameters into database,and still can load my last POST data into my textarea? So that next time I enter my website can see my last post content in my textarea.

Comment: Use cookies if you want to temporarily store data for your users

Comment: So is this a one time thing or you want to persist your variables for later use?

Comment: Besides cookies, you may also consider using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Mind that ideally neither cookies nor localStorage should be used to store confidential or security-related information.

Comment: Storing the data in Session object can solve the issue and can be differentiated on the basis of logged-in user.